# Adding Stock Status column to Manage Product Grid in Admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, stock

I'm trying to add 'stock status' column to the Admin Manage Product Grid. Stock status is either "In Stock" or "Out of Stock".

Seems like I need to edit `Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

### I added this line:

```
$this->addColumn('stock',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Stock Avail.'),
            'width' => '70px',
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',

            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/source_stock')->toOptionArray()
```

But  just prints out Array text....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code as mentioned by **Marius** in [**this**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29213/35223) answer.

In *Grid.php* file find `$this->setCollection($collection);` and before this code add following code (Join) :

```
$collection->joinTable(
    'cataloginventory/stock_status',
    'product_id=entity_id', 
    array("stock_status" => "stock_status"),
    null ,
    'left'
)->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status');
```

And now you can add column like :

```
$this->addColumn('stock_status',
     array(
        'header'=> 'Stock Status', 
        'width' => '60px',
        'index' => 'stock_status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => array('1'=>'In Stock','0'=>'Out Of Stock'),
));
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Hi Sanchit Gupta, I added this code but show an error that "Invalid attribute name: stock_status".

Comment: Try to reindex and flush the cache and let me know if its work or not?

Comment: Its working fine at my end. Please let me check for more detail